# Not completed file read

Tags: file-io, lua

I'm trying to debug what went wrong in my code. My `file.txt` contains 1763 lines but when I run it, it always ends up not completed. Always stops somewhere at 1680 and up (printed by the `row` in my code); the thing is it stops at different line every time I run it, so I don't think the problem's with my text file.

```
row = 0
for line in io.lines("file.txt") do 
  row = row+1
  local new_row1 = {}
  for n in line:gmatch'%S+' do
     table.insert(new_row1, tonumber(n))
  end
  if #new_row1 > 0 then
     table.insert(input, new_row1) 
  end
  print(row)
end
```

Is there something wrong in my code?

Comment: Does program terminate without error?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Yup. No error.

Comment: Add this line at the end of your code: `print('Done', row, #input)`.  Does it print different numbers every time?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Yes, different numbers every time. But, row and #input are always equal.

Comment: What is your file size in MBytes?

Comment: What happens if you comment out loop processing? Meaning comment out everything from `local newrow1 = {}` down to but not including `print(row)`? Does row equal to the number of lines in your file.txt?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff it's 64.7KB. I converted it to MB and it's 0.06318MB.

Comment: @greatwolf Yes, they're equal. That would only mean, the problem lies on putting the content of my file in the array. Can we do something to fix this?

Comment: Unbelievable.  Can you prepare test case (program + data file) and upload it somewhere so that everyone could reproduce this Lua behavior on their own systems?

Comment: What @Egor said. It's hard to tell why you're getting that behavior without knowing the actual input. It's possible your pattern isn't matching the lines in your file the way you think.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I'll update you guys once I have uploaded the test case.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Actually the code I posted above was not the entirety of my code, it was only a part of it. However, this one I uploaded was still not the whole, but it's basically what's needed to debug the code. [link](http://www.mediafire.com/folder/zr7ww6p41gl4d/Test_Case)

Comment: You must close your file with `file:close()` BEFORE reading from it with `for line in io.lines("file.txt") do`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like in your code, you opened a file handle to "file.txt" at the beginning of your script and it *remains* open till the end where you close the file. During that time, you attempt to reopen "file.txt" again in your loop which is causing the strange behavior you're seeing.

When I moved your file open and close scopes to the middle section after first loop but before the last outer loop, that fixes the issue:

```
file = assert(io.open("file.txt", "w"))
   for i = 1, 1000 do
      j = math.random(i, row-one)
      u[i], u[j] = u[j], u[i]
      for k = 1, 11 do
         file:write(input2[u[i]][k], " ")
      end
      file:write"\n"
   end
   num = (row-one)+1
   for i = 1, one do
     for k=1, 11 do
       file:write(input2[num][k], " ")    --writes to the file all the rows starting from where '1' in column11 was seen
     end
     file:write("\n")
     num = num + 1
   end
file:close()
-----------------------------------Access file.txt.--------------------------
-- ...
```

This gives the expected output:

```
Done    1762    1762
--------------------------
```